# Placing multiple tracking cookies with mod_usertrack module of apache

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies

We are using mod_usertrack module of Apache for tracking user activity on our website.

We wish to place additional tracking cookies to differentiate returning users on the website.

Can we place multiple tracking cookies using the mod_usertrack module?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question. Figured out that mod_usertrack module does not support multiple cookies. Our application now adds 2 cookies on the users browser, and the logging is done via Apache CustomLog.